# Git pre-receive hook to reject push with broken symbolic link

Tags: git, symlink

I am writing a pre-receive hook for a git remote. This pre-receive hook should reject a push if any of the changed objects in the push are broken (i.e., dangling) symlinks.

That is,

```
#!/bin/bash
# hooks/pre-receive
while read old_sha1 new_sha1 name ; do
  files=$(git diff --name-only $old_sha1..$new_sha1)
  # If a file in $files is a symbolic link pointing at nothing, non-zero exit
done
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over files and check if any of them is a broken symlink. To do that, you can use `test -e` to check for existence:

`for f in $files; do
    if [ ! -e "$f" ]; then
        # Problem if you reach here ...
        exit 1
    fi
done`

Note that my script above is not robust to whitespaces in filenames. Using `git diff --names-only -z` and splitting the result on `'\0'` properly would solve the issue.

Comment: The pre-receive hook runs on the remote git repository which is a "bare" repository. A bare repository does not have a working copy of the repository, or any of the working copy files in the usual directory layout. Thus, the above will not work.